# What do square brackets around a property name in an object literal mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been writing in JS for a while and have not used this form:

```
  dist: {
    files: {
      [bpr + 'lib/Monster.min.js']: ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
    }
  }
}
```

the

```
[]:[]
```

it works, I just have not used it or seen it before.

Comment: sorry, I did not say the environment, I'm using Grunt from the command line and this is the Gruntfile.js that grunt uses.  I needed a variable based key so I just tried it and it worked.  But the answer, is yes, this is correct JavaScript ES6 but no correct for ES5.

Comment: I read an article on ES6 and this probably should have been mentioned in the top 5 additions that ES6 give.  Very nice.

Comment: @cadegalt can you add the information about where this code can run in your question please?

Answer (score 60):

Only recently with ES6. They are called "computed property names"

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets `[]`, that will be computed as the property name.

Answer (score 6):

In ES6 square bracket is part of os the object literal when using computed key pairs.

For example:-

**Problem**
Below the string "key" times 5 makes a computed key named "key"*5, now without using square brackets this result in a syntax error

```
const newObject = {
    "key"*5:"value"
}
```

**The Solution**
The solution will be to use a square bracket before using a computed property as a key

```
const newObject = {
    ["key"*5]:"value"
}
```

For more reference of how to create objects check out this [link](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/object-literal-extensions/#:%7E:text=In%20ES6%2C%20the%20computed%20property,an%20expression%20for%20a%20property.)