# Javascript square brackets around method name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the RxJs doc I found following code snippet:

```
[rxSubscriberSymbol]() {
    return new SubjectSubscriber(this);
}
```

Its part of the [Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/Subject.js.html#lineNumber19) source code and is the first method right after the constructor.

So what do square brackets mean in this context?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean - that refers to object literals, but [the same principal applies for class properties](http://2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html#methods-in-class-definitions) apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

those are symbols, which is very similar to defining properties but gives different accessibility and testability functionality and they are completely unique,

you can read a lot more about metaprogramming here,
[Metaprogramming in ES6: Symbols and why they're awesome](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/)