# Array notation surrounding object key

Tags: javascript, generator

```
let obj = {
  a: 'alex',
  [Symbol.iterator] : function* () {
    yield this.a;
  }
}
```

Came across this code when learning about `Generator`. Wondering what is the term for such syntax `[Symbol.iterator]` where we use `[]` to surround object property? Can we apply it to any other property or it's only for `Symbol.iterator`?

Also, is it possible to make it reusable just like any other function for example as below code

```
let obj = {
  a: 'alex',
  [Symbol.iterator] : function* () {
    yield this.a;
  },
  getA: function() {
    return this.a
  }
}


console.log(obj.getA())//Perhaps obj.[Symbol.iterator]()............... ?
```

Comment: [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do square brackets around a property name in an object literal mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern JavaScript, a bracketed property name like `[Symbol.iterator]` means that the expression in the brackets should be evaluated to determine the property name in the declaration.

The expression `Symbol.iterator` evaluates to a `Symbol` instance for the distinguished property to identify the iterator function property of an iterable object.

In "old fashioned" JavaScript the code could have been written as:

```
let obj = {
  a: 'alex',
  getA: function() {
    return this.a
  }
};

obj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield this.a;
};
```

(Obviously that's not *really* "old-fashioned" JavaScript because the `Symbol` feature is new, but hopefully it's clear.)