# JavaScript syntax which looks like Array function: [variable] ({ key }, arg) { }

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was ask to study the code of employer, In the code, the employer did something like this:

```
export const actions = {
  [ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD.name] ({commit}, payload) {
    const type = payload
```

Now, In this, I am unable to rectify this line of code

```
 [ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD.name] ({commit}, payload) {
```

Like is it a function or what? Can someone explain me the above syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean

Answer (score 1):

New-ish JavaScript allows property names in object literal expressions (what that `{ }` block initializing `actions` is called) to *compute* property names from expressions by allowing `[ ]` for property names instead of identifiers or string constants as in the past.

So what that means is that `ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD.name` should be evaluated, and the string value of whatever that ends up being is used as the name of the function property of the object. (That too is a new-ish feature of the language; formerly properties had to be `name : value` strictly).

Now inside the formal parameter list to that function, `{commit}` is a *destructuring* formal parameter. What it means is that the function expects that the first argument will be an object, and so inside the function the parameter (variable) `commit` should be bound to the value of that object's "commit" property (or `undefined` if there is no such property).

So if we assume for example purposes that `ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD.name` evaluates to the string "xyz", then one would be able to call:

```
var result = actions.xyz({ foo: "bar", commit: "everything" }, somePayload);
```

and in the function the string "everything" would be the value of the `commit` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It uses object [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) syntax in combination with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parameter list.

`ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD` presumably evaluates to an object: accessing the `.name` property of the object probably evaluates to a string. For example, if the string is "foo", then the line there is equivalent to:

```
const actions = {
  'foo': function(arg1, payload) {
    let commit = arg1.commit; // using "let" because parameters can be reassigned
    const type = payload
    // ...
};
export actions;
```

(Technically, it's not *entirely equivalent*, but it nearly is - object methods can't be used as constructors.)

Answer (score 0):

> [ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD.name] ({commit}, payload) {

will resolve to function declaration syntax:

functionName (arguments) {
    statements
}

There are a couple of things playing into action here.
First, **actions** is an object.
Next, it uses new computed property name syntax.
i.e **[ACTIONS.ITEM_LIST.LOAD.name]** will provide functionName part of our syntax. Note, that this is not an array, it is a **computed property** which will also be a key of our actions dictionary.
Lastly, it uses **Shorthand method names** syntax to create a function in the object **actions** without writing it as **"key: value"** notation. This too is new in ECMAScript2015.

This link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) will give you clear idea if I don't clear all your doubts.