# How is this code updating the state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm confused about is the [event.target.name]: event.target.value in the argument for setState. I haven't seen this square bracket notation in Javascript before so I don't understand exactly why there's square brackets around the key.

```
onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
};
```

Not sure what Javascript construct I'm not understanding/missing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do square brackets around a property name in an object literal mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean)

Comment: Equivalent to `const state = {}; state[event.target.name] = event.target.value; this.setState(state);`. It's just a new shorter syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means the property name is dynamic and which is coming from `event.target.name` in this case.

I think the following example makes you understand it clearly

```js
const name = 'foo';

const obj1 = {
  name: 'bar'
}

const obj2 = {
  [name]: 'bar'
}

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

This prints

```
{ name: 'bar' }
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

Comment: Right, I understand that it's dynamic. But the author of this code put the square brackets around the key which is what I'm confused about.

Comment: You have to put them in brackets to use the actual value, I have updated my code with an example to show it

Answer (score -2):

Actually key of an object cant be a expression or function. So as here you are trying to set the key name from the event ...this syntax is used.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like a [WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

> The `target` property of the `Event` interface is a reference to the object that dispatched the event. It is different from `Event.currentTarget` when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

Normally a component in DOM(like input component) is passed to this function whenever its value is changed. You may see a more [complex example here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).