# Brackets in JS to get a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This works:

```
  handleOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value});
  }
```

`e.target.id` is wrapped in brackets (`[ ]`), while `e.target.value` is not.

I could write `e.target.value` in brackets too and it would work, but if I remove the brackets from `e.target.id` my code will not work. Why?

I did some research and believe this is because [Computed Property Names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34831282/9230154)  (I am not sure though), but then the question arises, why does the property of `e.target.id` needs to be computed while `e.target.value` does not? Both of them are simply values I would think.

Comment: `e.target.value` and `[e.target.value]` are not the same. The first will just represent the value while the last will create an array with one entry of the represented value.

Comment: Why the key needs to be computed here is something we can't tell you, because we don't know the context of this code; it depends on how the application that contains this code is constructed, and what the `this.setState()` method expects.

Comment: possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does the property of e.target.id needs to be computed while e.target.value does not?

The right hand side is *always* a value (and always has been).

The left hand side is, historically, a string or identifier. The ability to put an expression there (a computed property name) is a new feature.

```js
const foo = "bar";
// Here the property name is foo because it is an identifier
const obj = {
    foo: foo
};
console.log(obj);

// Here the property name is foo because it is a string
const obj2 = {
    "foo": foo
};
console.log(obj2);

// Here the property name is bar because it computed by evauating the constant
const obj3 = {
    [foo]: foo
};
console.log(obj3);


// Here the property name is barbar because it computed by evauating function call that returns a template string that uses the constant twice
function blah() {
    return `${foo}${foo}`;
}
const obj4 = {
    [blah()]: foo
};
console.log(obj4);


//This is the same as the previous example except that because the right hand side is always a value, wrapping the code in square brackets means it is treated as an array literal (as opposed to being a computed property which is what square brackets mean on the left hand side)
function blah() {
    return `${foo}${foo}`;
}
const obj5 = {
    [blah()]: [foo]
};
console.log(obj5);
```

Comment: These are great examples to make me fully understand what is going on, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Because `{foo.bar: "fizz"}` doesn't mean the same thing as `{"foo.bar": "fizz"}`, in fact that isn't even syntactically correct.

```js
const a = {b: "c"};
const foo = {a.b: "d"}; // error
console.log(foo);
```

also consider:

```js
const foo = {
  bar: "other"
};

const b = {
  [foo.bar]: "fizz", // Computed
  "foo.bar": "buzz", // String accessor
  // foo.bar: "err"  // Syntax error
};

console.log(b);
```

You want the value of `foo.bar` to be used as the key for the Object.  The language mechanism for doing that is to either extract the value and then use brackets to dereference it:

```
const buzz = {};
buzz[foo.bar] = "fizz";
```

or you use the new language feature to make it a one-liner:

```
const buzz = {[foo.bar]: "fizz"};
```

Answer (score 2):

> I could write e.target.value in brackets too and it would work, but if I remove the brackets from e.target.id my code will not work. Why?

Those two pair of brackets serve very different purpose: in

```
{ [keyName]: value }
```

you have indeed a computed property name. In

```
{ keyName: [value] }
```

however, the brackets around `[value]` create an array.