# Why square brackets allow use of variable value as object key?

Tags: javascript

code:

```
const x = 6;
const ob = {x: [6.1, 6.5]} 
console.log(ob) // {x: [6.1, 6.5]}

const y = 6;
const ob = {[y] : [6.1, 6.5]};
console.log(ob) // {6: [6.1, 6.5]}
```

Why square brackets allow use the value of the variable as object key, is this related to destructuring??

Comment: It's a special type of syntax known as computed property names. See: [What do square brackets around a property name in an object literal mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34831262)

Comment: thanks for that info,

Comment: It's not related to destructuring.  In your first example, the two "x"s have nothing to do with each other (the `const x` line is unused).  The syntax `ob["foo"]` is the same as `ob.foo`, but you can only use the latter syntax because "foo" is a valid identifier.  You could use `ob["foo-bar"]` but not `ob.foo-bar`.  The bracket syntax also allows you to use a property where you don't know the key at compile time, eg `const key = calculateKey();ob[key]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square brackets allow for computed property keys. In other words, the value of the variable inside of the square brackets is processed before the value is accessed.