# How do i get rid of "" in output? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, variables, let

With this code i want to achieve output `name: Gunnar` but I get `{ name: 'Gunnar' }`, how do I remove the `''` around Gunnar in the output?

```js
let keyName = "name";
let value = "Gunnar";

let person = {
   [keyName]: value
};

console.log(person)
```

I've guess it have something to do with the "value" but i can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: since when is using an array as a object property name legal? pretty sure it isn't..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are logging an _object_, which does not have the desired format. You need to create a _string_ with common string concatenation techniques.

Comment: @hanshenrik it called [Dynamic Keys](https://hackmamba.io/blog/2020/11/dynamic-javascript-object-keys/#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20object%20keys%20and,using%20dot%20or%20bracket%20notation.&text=This%20is%20pretty%20much%20standard,computation%20operations%20as%20a%20value.)

Comment: You can't get rid of the `"` since object keys and the value are strings

Comment: @hanshenrik since 2015/ES6. Well a bit earlier as major browser vendors implemented the feature before the official release of the spec but 2015 is probably correct enough. Also, not an "array", it's just part of the object initialiser for computer key name:[Why square brackets allow use of variable value as object key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62767821)

Comment: You’d need to write your own object-to-output library and not use console.log.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I mean, yes object keys are strings but that's not really relevant. The console will show them whatever way it wants. There is no requirement to show the quotes or not. [Firefox's console doesn't for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkLfn.png).

Comment: @VLAZ - they question is about the property value (which is a string) not the property name.

Comment: well, if you log like this `console.log("name: " + person.name)` then you'll get `name: Gunnar`

Comment: @Quentin the comment I responded to is about the property name.

Answer (score 4):

> With this code i want to achieve output `name: Gunnar` but I get `{ name: 'Gunnar' }`, how do I remove the `''` around `Gunnar` in the output?

Your code outputs an object using `console.log`. The [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) function will output it in the standard format for outputting objects in your environment. Nothing in your code is designed to create the output you want.

If you want the output `name: Gunnar`, then you need to change your `console.log` statement so you're outputting that text, rather than telling it to output an object, for instance:

```
console.log(`${keyName}: ${value}`);
```

```js
let keyName = "name";
let value = "Gunnar";

// No need for this:
// let person = {
//     [keyName]: value
// };

console.log(`${keyName}: ${value}`);
```

**If** you need `person` to be your starting point, but you still have access to `keyName`, then you can do it with [dynamic property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name), like this:

```
console.log(`${keyName}: ${person[keyName]}`);
```

```js
let keyName = "name";
let value = "Gunnar";

let person = {
    [keyName]: value
};

console.log(`${keyName}: ${person[keyName]}`);
```

**If** you don't want to use `keyName` *or* `value`, then it's not clear what you do want to do. Maybe you want to output multiple lines for each property:

```
for (const key in person) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${person[key]}`);
}
```

```js
let keyName = "name";
let value = "Gunnar";

let keyName2 = "age";
let value2 = 42;

let person = {
    [keyName]: value,
    [keyName2]: value2,
};

for (const key in person) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${person[key]}`);
}
```

Or maybe you're expecting an object with exactly one property (although doing that without knowing what the property name is isn't generally good practice):

```
const firstKey = Object.keys(person)[0];
if (firstKey) {
    console.log(`${firstKey}: ${person[firstKey]}`);
}
```

```js
let keyName = "name";
let value = "Gunnar";

let person = {
    [keyName]: value
};

const firstKey = Object.keys(person)[0];
if (firstKey) {
    console.log(`${firstKey}: ${person[firstKey]}`);
}
```

More to explore:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`for-in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Dynamic property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name)

Answer (score -2):

You can overwrite `console.log` so it removes `"` when printing

```js
const oldLog = console.log
const logger = (...args) => oldLog(args.map(arg => typeof arg === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(arg, null, 4).replace(/"/g, '') : arg).join(''))
console.log = logger

let keyName = "name";
let value = "Gunnar";

let person = {
   [keyName]: value,
};

console.log(person)
```