# Why does this array key get converted to a basic data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Currently, we're calling a 3rd party service with the following JavaScript object:

```
props = { ['356']: false, ['456']: true}
```

I notice that when I enter it into the Chrome browser console and re-inspect the object I get the following output:

```
props = { 356: false, 456: true}
```

What is going on here? Is '356' still a string after apparently being automatically casted from an object key that is an array of one string? It looks like it automatically got converted to an integer.

Comment: You can put any valid expression as object keys when you enclose them in `[]`. `['356']` translates to `365`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333702/1927991

Comment: Yes, it's still a string. Just like in `{propName: true}` the `propName` is a string. JavaScript objects do not have numeric property keys.

Comment: "*an object key that is an array of one string*" - no, it's not, it's a [computed property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34831262/1048572), with a string literal as the dynamic expression.

Answer (score 0):

`['356']` when used as an object key is not an array, it's using [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015), hence the conversion to the string `'356'`. Object keys are strings. You can test this with other types, for example in `{[function(){}]: 1}` they key is the string `'function(){}'`. If for whatever reason you need an array representation, you can call JSON.stringify, though that will give you back a JSON string with an array, not an array itself:

```
const foo  = { [JSON.stringify(['foo'])]: 1}
// "[\"foo\"]": 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys in object is always string. Next syntax isn't about array:

```js
props = { ['356']: false, ['456']: true}
```

Values in `[...]` is calculated in runtime, so:

```js
props = { [5 + 6]: false, ['a' + 'b']: true}
```

is the same as:

```js
props = { '11': false, 'ab': true}
```

Comment: Actually, they can be a Symbol as well