# What is this strange javascript object syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this is a strange question for a strange syntax I've found and I can't explain the reason why one would use it:

```
let ranges = [];

// field and value are simple strings
for (const [field, value] of Object.entries(this.$route.query)){ 
  ranges.push({ [field] : value }); // << Note the 'array' syntax
}
```

Now, that `[field]` makes quite no sense to me. Why would one use that 'array' syntax? Also, I thought it wasn't even possible to assign an array as an object key. And also, if I log the resulting object, I can see that `[field]` is in fact converted to `"field"`.  In other words, just like writing

```
ranges.push({ field : value });
```

Am I missing something or the `{ [field] : value }` is quite useless?

Comment: this syntax is part of ECMAScript 6 (ES6) and allows you to use an expression inside square brackets [] for object property names. Is not creating an array as an object key

Comment: `field` is a variable. if you just use `field: value`, the property will be called `field`, not whatever value is assigned to it.

Comment: `{ field: value }` creates an object with a `field` property. `{ [field]: value }` creates an object with a property whose name is whatever the **value** of the `field` variable is. See [the first linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831262/what-do-square-brackets-around-a-property-name-in-an-object-literal-mean).

Comment: @ChrisG G Ok but that makes sense if a property must be computed. In this case, `field` is always a simple string. So why should one 'compute' it?

Comment: @Jorg ok! now it's more clear to me, thank you!

Comment: @LucaReghellin But here it _is_ computed... it's not literally `"field"`, it's whatever key was in `this.$route.query` at that point... you can't know it in advance. (If you observed it becoming literally `field` then you had an unlucky example where `this.$route.query` also had `{ field: 123 }` and not something like `{ abc: 123, def: 456 }`...)

Comment: Yes, your right, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

the use of `{ [field]: value }` is not useless, it allows you to dynamically set the key of the object based on the value of the field variable.

```js
let field = 'example';
let value = 50

// Using computed property names
let obj1 = { [field]: value };
console.log(obj1); // Output: { example: 50 }

// Without computed property names
let obj2 = { field: value };
console.log(obj2); // Output: { field: 50 }
```